# OSX terminal tilde bash complete

Tags: macos, terminal, bash-completion

On my Linux box, when I type

```
$ cd ~/Des[TAB]
```

it completes to `~/Desktop/`.

But in OSX terminal doing the same thing expands to `/Users/username/Desktop/`.

This appears rather annoying to me as it 'jumps' and also takes more space. Can I somehow get the former behaviour?

Comment: I can´t reproduce this behaviour, have you enabled some kind of special expansion features in your .bash_profile? Look for lines beginning with `shopt` and `export`..

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Just suddenly started happening to me today, running Yosemite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't ever picked up on this behavior before, but my shell on OS X shows the former behavior (expanding `cd ~/Des[TAB]` to `cd ~/Desktop/`).  Unfortunately I don't have a good answer as to why.  Dumb luck, I guess.

That said, [here is a similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/95653/bash-shell-tab-completion-dont-expand-the) that discusses some ways to turn it off.  Additionally, here is [another in-depth discussion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-stop-bash-from-replacing-~-with-home-username-643162/) talking about the Linux-y way to enable/disable the feature.  Hope one of 'em works for you.